# JavaScript calculating length of a string

Tags: javascript, string, counting

Why when I try this block of code:

```
var str = "1234";
alert(str.toString().lenght);
```

it alerts me 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 7):

You misspelled `length`. It's "length":

```
str.toString().length
```

You don't actually need the `toString()` call here, though. `"1234"` is already a string, so `str.length` works as well.

Comment: Ah. dyslexic moments are always such fun. i always type "ponit" instead of "point" for some reason. usually I catch them...

Comment: I edited, but my post initially read "You *mispelled*". Oops.

Answer (score 1):

correct your spelling...

alert(str.toString().lengTH);

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in that code. It's `length` not lenght.

But aside from that, there's no need to call `toString()`. `str.length` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo: it's `.length` ;)